# Attribute Set to much load in product page admin side in magento 2.3.3!

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, attribute-set, loading

I have Magento site in 2.3.3 version, I have created the attribute set in the admin side using the default Magento attribute set option. - https://prnt.sc/qs3wiq

on my site like 100000+ products with different attribute options.

but when I open attribute set option - https://prnt.sc/qs3wsm

so gives this error( AW, Snap error )

I think this issue is loading because one attributes have many options.

but how can I solve this problem Please anyone tell me.

I have tierd to solve this problem.

Comment: Add exact error.

Comment: the exact error I can not put in question because the image is not uploaded in question  so I can put error text into the question.

Comment: Try to upload it in question.

Comment: yes mitesh I can try many times but the image is not upload

Comment: just out of interest, how do you manage 100000+ products? Images updates, price changes, descriptions etc ?

Comment: our product only name, price and attribute value change otherwise all item are the same images,etc.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the max_input_vars problem but without seeing more of your code I am not sure.

Set max_input_vars to 10000 in php.ini and restart your web server (or php-fpm) and then give it another go.

Comment: but this issue is the default. we can not customize anything for that.
we can only import the product.

Comment: If you run phpinfo what do you get for max_input_vars?

Comment: in phpinfo max_input_vars 1000

Comment: Update it to 10000 and give it another go. Remember to reset the web server - apache, nginx, php-fpm or whatever is reading the php.ini file.

Comment: Okay I will check...